# What kind of pressure / strain gauge is this?

Tags: pressure, force-measurement

This is a photo of the backside of a diaphragm strain measurement element. I'm researching strain gauge operating principles, and the one shown below is eluding me.

This is not a resistive strain gauge (where resistive traces increase & decrease in cross sectional area, accompanied by proportional changes in resistivity). This is most likely a capacitive strain gauge, but I'm asking Engineering StackExchange to provide more detail on how it is made and how it operates. Specifically, how does the pictured pattern convert strain into changes in an electrical property.

[image: back side of diaphragm strain measurement element]

The substrate appears to be some kind of plated insulator or dielectric, lithographed, then chemically etched. What is the name of this kind of sensor?

Comment: Consider adding a tag 'strain-measurement'?

Comment: What do you have in mind when you ask for the "kind"? The axis of measurement? Design? EDIT: Now that I read more carefully, I think you want to know the principle of operation? As far as I know all strain gauges are resistive.

Comment: Metal changes properties when deformed.  The biggest changes to electrical resistance can be approximated from the change in geometry using resistivity.  That will get you a theoretical model.  For a usable one, a strain gage must be calibrated - apply stress, measure resistance.  Maybe even repeat at different temperatures you might use it at...

Comment: Thanks, DGNguyen. I don't think it's a resistive strain gauge. It is more likely capacitive. I'll edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: The circuit schematic on the face of the device suggests that OP is right that it's capacitative rather than resistive.  It also appears to be set up to measure two perpendicular components of longitudinal strain, not just one.

Comment: ... or is it hard-wired as a subtractor between the two components to measure deviatoric strain?  Intriguing.

Comment: which device is that from?

Comment: @jsotola, it's the backside of a very small pressure sensor, measuring liquid pressure in a life science instrument. Maximum pressure is ~25 MPa / 3600 PSI.

Comment: @DanielHatton it's a pressure sensor, so it is measuring the strain on a diaphragm - so I believe you're correct.

Comment: @jsotola it is from a high pressure biotech lab instrument. Here's the page:
https://www.cytivalifesciences.com/en/us/shop/chromatography/tools-and-accessories/valves-accessories-and-spare-parts/column-valve-kit-v9h-c-p-04116

Comment: The etched pattern does not conduct, so it looks more like two plates separated by a distance. Any leads on papers or websites describing this type of sensing would be helpful.